# Mono.Cecil - How can I found out PInvoke DLL name?

Tags: cil, mono.cecil

Mono.Cecil provides a way to check whether a method is pinvoke or not with `method.IsPInvokeImpl`, and also provides more info with `method.PInvokeInfo`. How can I find out dll name ?

Comment: Does it have `.Attributes`? The relevant data is part of the `DllImportAttribute` metadata (specifically, `Value`).

Comment: `.Attributes` is an enum, also `method.HasCustomAttributes` returns false.

Comment: Ah. My bad, `DllImport` is just hoopla for the C# compiler to pretend. The actual IL contains the entry point data as part of the `pinvokeimpl` attribute. Doesn't `.PInvokeInfo` have what you need in the `.Module.Name`? (I'm going strictly by the Cecil source code here, no actual code to test with.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert, correct. Post the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IL for P/Invoke methods looks like this (for example, `kernel32!LockFile`):

```
.method assembly hidebysig static pinvokeimpl("kernel32.dll" lasterr winapi) 
    bool LockFile (
        class Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle handle,
        int32 offsetLow,
        int32 offsetHigh,
        int32 countLow,
        int32 countHigh
    ) cil managed preservesig 
{
}
```

Mono.Cecil mirrors the `pinvokeimpl` metadata in the [`PInvokeInfo`](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/master/Mono.Cecil/PInvokeInfo.cs) class, with the first string packaged up as a `ModuleReference`. Hence, `method.PInvokeInfo.Module.Name` gives the DLL/dylib name.